# How to permanently save the content of /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolv.conf, etc

As I mentioned in the title, ctrl+s doesn't permanently save the content of that file, if I rebooted my machine I lost all the configuration I did in there, an help, please.

Comment: use `sudo apt install resolvconf`

Comment: In modern systems, `/etc/resolv.conf` is a (symbolic link to a) dynamically generated file that is not intended to be edited by hand

Comment: Your question should detail what configuration you are doing in that file; there might be better places for it.

Comment: At the top of the file: `# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.`

Comment: @user535733, i'm working on DNS

Comment: DNS settings should be detailed in /etc/netplan or in your NetworkManager settings

Answer (score 2):

If you have `# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.`, at the top of the file, then you can edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`.

It's not the same syntax as `/etc/resolv.conf`, but `man resolved.conf` will help you.

Once the file is saved:
`sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`

And check that the `/etc/resolv.conf` is updated.